# Pandas, arithmetic operation on grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

let say I have a pandas data frame and already grouped as

```
grp=df.groupby(['a','b' ]).sum()
```

[image]

now I would like to calculate for every group `a` , the percentage of `b` for each column ,
for example: `P1, aaaa = 11/484`, `P1, aaac = 8/357`, `N1, aaaa = 61/7183` so on ....

**Reproducible grouped data**

```
pd.DataFrame({'aaaa': {('P 1', 0): 484,('P 1', 1): 11,}})
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind posting some data as code, not as image?

Comment: provide a reproducible example plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
grp.loc[(slice(None), 1),:].droplevel(1)/grp.loc[(slice(None), 0),:].droplevel(1)
```

In practice whith `grp.loc[(slice(None), 1),:]` and `grp.loc[(slice(None), 0),:]` I extract only the rows with `b==1` and `b==0` (try yourself and see the output); after that I need to remove the `b` level (`.droplevel(1)`) to make these two objects have the same index (the columns are already shared); finally I divided this two matrices with `/` (now I can do it because now they have same index and columns). Hope it is clear :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xs` to a select particular level of a MultiIndex:

```py
out = df.xs(1, level=1) / df.xs(0, level=1)
```

Output:

```py
         aaaa
P 1  0.022727
```